# Windows 7, View fingerprint scans on screen

Tags: windows-7, fingerprint, biometrics

I use the biometrics fingerprint reader in Windows 7 using an HP nc4400 laptop.

Everything works really well.

From a purely "cool/geek" factor I'd like to see the images of the fingerprint scans. I'm sure I remember with XP and HP's own software it used to show the scan as you logged.

Is there anyway to use the fingerprint reader in windows 7 and see the images as they're scanned?

Comment: Don't! Jamie and Adam might see that image and we know what that means: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MAfAVGES-Yc ;-) (footage 2006)

Comment: What is the fingerprint reader you're using? For what I've seen [here](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ca/en/sm/WF06b/12139188-12139280-12139280-12139280-12434628-12399232-77987855.html?dnr=1) your laptop doesn't have one builtin.

Comment: @criziot at the top right part of the monitor there is a biometric reader.

Comment: @Thomas Shields have you tried the XP driver to see the images as OP mentioned?

Comment: What software were you using on Windows XP?

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://blog.irwan.name/?p=471) details how to see the scans from Linux. You could probably compile the aes2501 utility for Windows and use that, or integrate it into your own application.

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: It's on the web archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20170622104123/http://blog.irwan.name/?p=471